# In 'edit interactions', what is the difference between filter and highlight?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to understand the edit interactions option in power bi.

In 'edit interactions', what is the difference between filter and highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters remove all but the data you want to focus on. Highlighting isn't filtering. It doesn't remove data, but instead highlights a subset of the visible data; the data that isn't highlighted remains visible but dimmed.

check out this link to understand better

https://medium.com/@smitagudale712/filter-vs-highlight-and-spotlight-in-power-bi-ddc9e611984c

Comment: What is the default

Comment: @variable default one is filter.                                                                                                  p.s. If this (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in".